# Why the comparaison operator "is" doesn't work?

Tags: python, comparison

The comparison operator ***is*** doesn't work. I don't understand why both variables have the same ID.

[image]

Comment: Please post your code as text, no screenshots.

Comment: Unfortunately, the linked question doesn't really answer your question. When you create integers, you get a new object even though they are the same value. `is` is `False` because they are two separate 500 objects. Except sometimes python reuses the same object. Integers are immutable so its safe. When python compiles a .py file, it keeps track of integers its already created and reuses them. That's what happened in `%Run`. And python also caches integers from, um I think -4 to 255, so `is` will be True.

Comment: BUT, never depend on that. Use `==` instead of `is` for integers.